# Make curl work on ssh connection

Tags: windows-xp, curl

On my windows xp machine, I can connect to a remote host via putty and psftp. However I fail to establish a connection with curl. When I enter

```
curl -v --key priv_key.ppk --pubkey pub_key.pub sftp://user@domain.com/~
```

I get

```
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password
* Using ssh public key file pub_key.pub
* Using ssh private key file priv_key.ppk
* SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file
```

I did use the export feature of puttygen to generate a curl comliant private key file, but I do not know how to provide a working public key file. Any hints?

Comment: Open your private key with putty key gen.  The public key is displayed in the dialog box.  You can select the displayed key, and copy/paste it into a text file.

Comment: Thanks, I did copy this into the authorized_keys file on the server and also into a local copy of the pubkey file that is passed to curl as an argument. I still get the same error message...